# How can I achieve having 2 different fall speeds for my player?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the example video, when the player walks off the ledge he immediately transitions into a slowed down fall state but when the player jumps, he's allowed to fall quickly unless there is no platform underneath him, in which case he transitions into the slower fall state. How can I achieve this in my game?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZfdQPAM9OE&feature=youtu.be

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There so many way, I'll give you one simple example:

You need set up a simple scene where you have a character (e.g capsule) with **rigidbody** (`Use Gravity` set to false) and **collider**, and many grounds (e.g cube) with **collider**, and set the tag of all grounds to `ground`, then change the view to 2D

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float slowFallSpeed = 1f;
    public float normalFallSpeed = 3f;
    public float runSpeed = 5f;
    bool aboveGround = false;
    bool touchGround = false;
    bool inFall = false;
    bool inJump = false;
    const string k_Ground = "ground"; // Tag of ground object.
    float maxRaycastDist = 2;
    float currentFallSpeed = 0f;
    Rigidbody rg;
    void Start() 
    {
        rg = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        if (col.transform.CompareTag(k_Ground) && aboveGround)
            touchGround = true;
    }

    void OnCollisionExit(Collision col)
    {
        if (col.transform.CompareTag(k_Ground))
            touchGround = false;
    }

    void FixedUpdate() 
    {
        // Check if character above the ground
        RaycastHit[] hits = Physics.RaycastAll(transform.position, Vector3.down, maxRaycastDist);
        aboveGround = false;
        foreach (var hit in hits)
        {
            if (hit.transform.CompareTag(k_Ground))
            {
                aboveGround = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Move
        Vector3 moveDir = Vector3.zero;
        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
            moveDir += new Vector3(1f, 0f);
        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
            moveDir += new Vector3(-1f, 0f);

        inJump = Input.GetKey("w") && !inFall;
        if (inJump)
            moveDir += new Vector3(0f, 1f);
        
        rg.position += moveDir.normalized * runSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

        // Fall
        if (!touchGround && !inFall && !inJump)
        {
            inFall = true;
            currentFallSpeed = aboveGround ? normalFallSpeed : slowFallSpeed;
        }
        else if (touchGround && inFall)
        {
            inFall = false;
            currentFallSpeed = 0f;
        }

        if (currentFallSpeed != 0f)
            rg.position += Vector3.down * currentFallSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    }
}
```

You could using different settings and differen component or in the 2D space, but logic should be the same

Comment: Thank you for this, I really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.